# Minecraft Bedrock Structureless Superflat: Is there a way of making this T-Flip-Flop simpler?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

So I've been playing on a Bedrock 1.20.30 structureless superflat (no mods), no access to stone, lava, quartz; and therefore only have access to things like pressure plates, trapdoors, redstone torches, redstone dust, rails (standard, activator and powered), minecarts, tripwire hooks, string, etc.

I've wanted to create the TFF to help switch mob flow to alternate distribution of zombies from a new mob grinder, which will use [Birmioh's mob sorter](https://youtu.be/KnFl6uXsJ5Q?si=cLfIp5JMXJnULhfN) to separate witches, zombies, creepers and skeletons from one another... I wanted to use the TFF to flick half of the zombies to be drowned to convert to Drowned to obtain their copper, I figured I'd be using a trapdoor and water streams to redirect zombies to two different areas.

This TFF is something I cobbled together with what I have available to me, but I'm not sure if this can be made simpler, or if there is a simpler circuit that can be made given the resource restrictions I have... Appreciate any suggestions...

BTW, the pigs in the sandbox world I've used to create this circuit seem to have an affinity to minecrafts... it's not critical to the circuit...

[image: Off-state]

[image: On-state]